# Lock object origin to 3D cursor

Tags: animation, objects, 3d-cursor, origin

I have some problems about animating multiple objects since they're not moving at the same speed and because of that it doesn't seem like the objects are connected during the animation but only in the two frames ''locked'' the 
It seems like it's because they have origins in different spots, so I set all origins to the 3D cursor in the absolute center, but as soon as I move the objects the origin follows and leaves the 3D cursor... Is it possible to lock the origin to the 3D cursor so it stays there even when you move your object?

I know that I can just move the object and then replace the origin back to the 3D cursor, but then the animation goes crazy, so another idea?

Pic 1) This is what I'm starting with. All parts have to be animated, but since the white parts only move up and down, there's no problem, but the blue parts have to be rotated, and that's when it goes wrong during animation...

Pic 2) This is where the animation should end. Notice that the spikes marked with a red dot never leave the standard plane (the red line).
It looks fine in the first and last frame of the animation, but the time in between go crazy.. doesn't move at the same speed, rotate around, and the spikes aren't at the red line through the whole time.

Pic 3) The blue parts are just connected to the white part as you see it in this picture... The blue ring just has du stay around the white peak, and don't break the laws of physic by moving in between or through the object.

Pic 4) This is just the full ''product'' so you have a better idea.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely look into [rigging](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/rigging/introduction.html). It's often used to animate characters, but has a place anywhere you're trying to deform an object like this.

I would add several [bones](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/rigging/armatures/bones/introduction.html) along your shape, then parent the shape to the armature [using envelope weights](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/rigging/armatures/skinning/parenting.html#with-envelope-weights). See [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/rigging/armatures/introduction.html).

Comment: The objects aren't connected like that... They all have one single spot, that should be able to rotate about one specific spot of another object, which all of the first mentioned objects are connected to, but in different spots... it's a little hard to explain, but do you understand?

Comment: Hm. I think I know what you mean, you should check out [rigging](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/rigging/introduction.html). Do you want them to pivot freely, with physics, or just be animated but appear to be locked to one spot on the parent?

Comment: I have to say that I don't know exactly what you mean, so what about some pictures du demonstrate?... 

Pic 1) This is what I'm starting with. All parts have to be animated, but since the white parts only move up and down, there's no problem, but the blue parts have to be rotated, and that's when it goes wrong during animation...

Comment: Pic 2) This is where the animation should end. Notice that the spikes marked with a red not never leave the standard plane (the red line).
It looks fine in the first and last frame of the animation, but the time in between go crazy.. doesn't move at the same speed, rotate around, and the spikes aren't at the red line through the whole time.

Comment: Pic 3) I said earlier that the blue parts were connected to some of the white parts, but there just connected as you see on this picture... The blue ring just has du stay around the white peak, and don't break the laws of physic by moving in between or through the object.

Pic 4) This is just the full ''product'' so you have a better idea.

Comment: Instead of using comments, please edit your question and clarify what we're supposed to understand from the images.

Comment: Thanks for providing more info. I can see where the blue things start, but where do they end up (on the last frame)?

Comment: The first frame is picture 1, the last frame is picture 2... if that's what you meant?

Comment: Yes, thank you. So you're trying to slide the marked points along the X-axis while keeping the tops/bottoms stationary?

Comment: Stationary along with the white ''lock'', yes

Comment: Completely redid the question, hope this helps.